# Fine Uploader doesn't resume with "retry"

Tags: fine-uploader

I was wondering why the resume function works if you navigate away from an upload but it does not work when you use the retry link.
I am using S3 uploader and here is my enabled setting 
            retry: {
                enableAuto: true
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },

Now when I navigate away from the page during an upload, close the browser , then come back I can resume the upload by starting a new upload of the same file.

However, if I deliberately disable the network adapter and let it error, then turn the network back on , I would expect to be able to hit retry and it start from where it stopped. It does not, it starts back at the beginning.

Would someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

Fine Uploader will always either resume or retry starting with the last failed chunk.  My tests show that this is functioning correctly with Fine Uploader S3 5.0.8.  If you are seeing something different, please open up a bug case with all of your code and a detailed description of the issue along with the reproduction steps in the Github project's issue tracker.

Comment: I think I have sourced the reason this was happening.

Comment: I was uploading a video that was already in my S3 bucket. So it looks like it will not resume if the whole file is already there,. when I try with a video not already in the bucket I get correct retry attempt.